# Using premade code with only one command in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am quite a new coder in Java, I have already used it before but without going deep into it, but now that I learned the basic I am searching for a way to be more efficient in my way of coding, so I ask how could I do lines of code to run one after another each time I use a certain word, for example, I would like my code to run several fighting commands that I premade using only the word "fight" in my code

Comment: Do you mean like.. creating a method that contains all the code you want to be executed when there is a fight and then calling the method if you enter the word "fight"?

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you now I got the name of thee thing I want to do

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set up a scanner that waits for a string input after which is process the string received through the scanner and if said string is "fight" then call the fight method.

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String command = in.next();
    in.close();
    ProcessCommand(command);
}

static void ProcessCommand(String command) {
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("fight")) {
        fight();
    }
}

static void fight() {
    // Do Stuff..
}
```

Hope this helps! :D